# Python Speech Error

Tags: python, output, traceback

I have been working all day trying to get a Python program that does various things working.  Since I got most of the code for another person, I have been spending most of my time ironing out errors, but now, I have one that I just can't overcome.

Below is the code and below that is the output.

```
import speech 
import datetime
import speakWebPage 
import os 
import Weather 
import ReadMail


def getCurrentTime():
    """
        Returns the properly formatted current time
    """
    now = datetime.datetime.now();
    hr = now.hour
    greeting = ""
    ampm = ""
    if (hr < 12): #morning
        hr = hr
        greeting = "morning"
        ampm = "am"
    elif(hr>=12 and hr <1): #afternoon
        hr = hr-12
        greeting = "afternoon"
        ampm = "noon"
    elif(hr>12 and hr <19): #evening
        hr = hr-12
        greeting = "evening"
        ampm = "pm"
    else:
        hr = hr -12
        greeting = "night"
        ampm = "pm"
    return [str(hr) + 'O' + str(now.minute), ampm, ' in the ', greeting]

def morning_greetings():
   speech.say ("Good Morning.")
   speech.say(" It is "+''.join(getCurrentTime()))
   speech.say(Weather.getCurrentWather())
   check_mails()

def check_mails():
    speech.say("Checking mails. Please wait ...")
    count = ReadMail.getUnreadMailCount()
    if (count <= 0):
        speech.say("You have NO unread mails")
    else:
        speech.say("You have "+ str(count) + " unread mails")

def handleCallback(phrase, listner):
    #speech.say('You said %s' % phrase)

    if phrase == "jarvis" or phrase == "jaiss":
        print (phrase)
        speech.say("Yes Boss")

    elif phrase == "are you up":
        speech.say("definitely. at your service sir!")

    elif phrase == "what is the current time":
        speech.say(getCurrentTime())

    elif phrase == "turn off":
        print (phrase)
        speech.say("Turning Off")
        listner.stoplistening()

    elif phrase == "how are you":
        print (phrase)
        speech.say("I am good. Thank you. How are you.")

    elif phrase == "read news":
        print (phrase)
        feeds = speakWebPage.readFeeds()
        speech.say(feeds)

    elif phrase == "show my feeds":
        print (phrase)
        speech.say("Launching Google Reader")
        os.system("C:\Users\kshwetabh\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
    reader.google.com")

    elif phrase == "how is the weather outside":
        speech.say("Getting current weather. Please wait...!")
        print (phrase)
        speech.say(Weather.getCurrentWather())

    elif phrase == "get me the weather forecast":
        speech.say("Getting weather forecast. Please wait...!")
        print (phrase)
        speech.say("This week's weather forecast:")
        for item in Weather.getWeatherForecast():
            speech.say(item)

    elif phrase == "any new mails":
        check_mails()
        print (phrase)

    elif phrase == "morning greetings":
        morning_greetings()

    else:
        print (phrase)
        speech.say("Could not understand, please repeat")

listner = speech.listenfor(['jarvis', 'jaiss', 'turn off',
                        'how are you', 'read news', 
                        'stop' , 'show my feeds', 
                        'what is the current time', 
                        'are you up', 'how is the weather outside', 
                        'get me the weather forecast', 
                        'any new mails', '*', 'morning greetings'], handleCallback)

import time

while listner.islistening():
     time.sleep(1)
     #print "Waiting for Command"
```

Output (errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\JAVIS\JAISS-master\first.py", line 113, in
 <module>
'any new mails', '*', 'morning greetings'], handleCallback)   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/speech.py", line 206, in listenfor
return _startlistening(phraselist, callback)   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/speech.py", line 222, in
 _startlistening
context = _recognizer.CreateRecoContext()   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py\C866CA3A-32F7-11D2-9602-00C04F8EE628x0x5x4.py",
line 2640, in CreateRecoContext
ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(10, LCID, 1, (9, 0), (),) com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None,
0, -2147200904), None)
```

Comment: An exception happened somewhere inside the `speech` package that you are importing. It appears to execute Windows COM calls, presumably to connect to a native component that does the actual sound recognition. Maybe your speech recognition service is incorrectly configured?

Comment: Python says your callback handleCallback is None

Comment: If you have found a solution to the problem please post it as an answer to the question.